# Pad an image with zeros

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am coding in C++ and am trying to resize image 2 to the same dimensions as image 1, however I don't want to stretch the image. I am trying to copy image2 to the padded matrix (at the point 0,0). Am getting the error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed `(0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows)` in `Mat`, file C:\opencv\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 323

Code is below. Thanks in advance

```
    Mat padded;
    padded.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));
    padded.create(image1.rows,image1.cols, image2.type());
    image2.copyTo(padded(Rect(0, 0, image2.rows, image2.cols)));
```

Comment: Assertion failure means any of the mentioned condition get failed. Just check all the parameter which are mentioned in the assert condition and you will know why this is happening.

Comment: image2.copyTo(padded(Rect(0, 0, image2.rows, image2.cols))); // you swapped rows & cols

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OpenCV function [`copyMakeBorder`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder) to pad an image:

To achieve what you want, you can try the following:

```
cv::Mat padded;

//Assuming that dimensions of image1 are larger than that of image2
//Calculate padding amount so that total size after padding is equal to image1's size
int rowPadding = image1.rows - image2.rows;
int colPadding = image1.cols - image2.cols;

cv::copyMakeBorder(image2, padded, 0, rowPadding, 0, colPadding, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));
```

Comment: When i use the code you provided it fails and displays the error: penCV Error: Assertion failed (top >= 0 && bottom >= 0 && left >= 0 && right >= 0) in copyMakeBorder, file C:\opencv\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\utils.cpp, line 208

Comment: gotit working I relised image2 number of cols was larger than image1. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Adsa.. Well if it is working, you may consider accepting the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

It is almost the same as [I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281826/add-small-image-to-large-image-for-oclmat-in-opencv). As for you exmple, you just swap cols and rows in function call as berak already mentioned above.

Method copyMakeBorder(...) exists both for Mat and oclMat, so it could be usefull if you will try openCL-extension of openCV for better perfomance.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the syntax, but here's a pseudo-code

```
float width1, height1; //size of image1
float width2, height2; //original size of image2
float scale;

bool portrait = width2 < height2;

if(portrait) scale = height1 / height2;
else scale = width1 / width2;

float scaled_width2 = width2 * scale;
float scaled_height2 = height2 * scale;
```

When the image is portrait, we fill height, otherwise we fill the width.
By doing it this way, the image will get to its maximum size without being stretched